# How can I make text stand on top of a div?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a menu on top of a div, so basically the text is on top of it (see example).
I want to have the text of the menu inside that same div, so the html is something like this:

```
<div id="text">
            <div id="menu">Portfolio &nbsp;|&nbsp; About us</div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You can put that text inside some block element (<p> for example) and give that element a negative top margin:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Position the div relatively (`position: relative;`), and then the text absolutely (`position:absolute;`). Make sure the text is inside an element inside the div, and then set the nested element's `top` position to a negative number until it is positioned to your liking.

To center it, you will need to mess about with `left` and `right` properties.

Comment: Using absolute here is not necessary

Comment: No, but it takes it out of the flow inside the div, so it shouldn't mess with anything (however unlikely that is).

Answer (score 2):

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uPkhW/) just about mimicks your screenshot.

I had to add this to the `#menu` styling:

```
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
line-height: 1em;
```

And then this to `#text p`:

```
margin-top: 0;
```

And that did the trick.

Making it all centered was as simple as this:

```
#text {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative/absolute positioning or try something like this

```
     <div id="text">
          <div id="menu">Portfolio &nbsp;|&nbsp; About us</div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
```

And in your css:

```
    #text{
       text-align:center;
    }
    #menu{
      margin-top:-20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/rVjCB/

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="top">
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>About us</li>
    </ul>
    Text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
    background:#957F00;
    max-width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:white;
}
.menu>.top{
    background:white;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:black;
}

.menu>.top>li{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    border-left:3px solid #957F00;
    margin-left:-3px;
    text-align:center;
}
```